# jQuery UI TimePicker Addon DropDowns Auto-Close

Tags: jquery, firefox, bootstrap-datetimepicker

We've add the jQuery UI TimePicker control to the normal jQuery DatePicker control and are having an issue with FireFox only.

When you select the time drop downs in FireFox, they immediately close so you can't select a time.

Everything works fine in Chrome & IE, this is just FireFox.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If yes then why don't you use bootstrap datetime picker? It is much more extensive and powerful tool.

Comment: The code works fine everywhere else and we're on a bit of a time crunch to get this code released so changing over to bootstrap isn't really feasible at this point.

We also like the look and feel of the jQuery datetimepicker.

I tried doing a quick test with the bootstrap one and it kept saying $ was not defined.